# Add CDataElements to DOMConfiguration

Tags: xml, cdata, xerces

I'm generating XML using `LSSerializer`. The problem is that with `OutputFormat` I can set an array of `CData`, but I can't do it with the `DOMConfiguration` that I get from the `LSSerializer`.

This is the old version :

```
OutputFormat of = new OutputFormat();
String[] arrayOfCDATAHandledElements = { "^Tag1", "^Tag2" };
of.setCDataElements(arrayOfCDATAHandledElements);
```

And the new version :

```
LSSerializer domWriter = impls.createLSSerializer();            
DOMConfiguration domConfig = domWriter.getDomConfig();
String[] arrayOfCDATAHandledElements = { "^Tag1", "^Tag2" }; // how would one add it?
domConfig.setParameter("cdata-sections", Boolean.TRUE);
```

I want the CDATA to be added for Tag1 & Tag2 in my XML.

Answer (score 0):

While I can see this question is from 2012, I ran into this same issue while recently trying to fix some very old code.  From what I can tell, when you build your document, you should be making sure that any nodes that need to have CDATA markers are built as follows:

```
org.w3c.dom.CDATASection commentTextNode = 
    document.createCDATASection("My Comment with funky !@#$ characters");
```

This is in contrast to how OutputFormat handled CDATA by specifying which elements (by name) needed to be formatted as CDATA.